# How to skip tests in PHPunit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I am using phpunit in connection with jenkins, and I want to skip certain tests by setting the configuration in the XML file `phpunit.xml`

I know that I can use on the command line:

`phpunit --filter testStuffThatBrokeAndIOnlyWantToRunThatOneSingleTest`

how do I translate that to the XML file since the `<filters>` tag is only for code-coverage?

I would like to run all tests apart from `testStuffThatAlwaysBreaks`

Comment: KO: what about fixing the test? btw, hi from welly ;-)

Comment: I didn't write the tests, it's something irrelevant, and also don't want to change the core files

Comment: Doubtfully you can do so. It is a very strange requirement

Comment: PS: you mentioned filters - but it couldn't help you, because it excludes all the path. Otherwise `<exclude>` - would do the work for you

Comment: can you post the proposed phpunit.xml.dist file?

Comment: The requirement was to run all the tests on my project but remove the framework tests - I didn't need to run their tests on my CI

Answer (score 284, accepted):

The fastest and easiest way to skip tests that are either broken or you need to continue working on later is to just add the following to the top of your individual unit test:

```
$this->markTestSkipped('must be revisited.');
```

Comment: you can always add directories or tests to the xml config file, however, if this is a controller or similar that's really not very practical because you probably have dozens of other tests in that file.  i guess if you have no access to unit tests, not sure i understand why, then you have no other choice than to exclude.

Comment: As it is a static method (at least in PHPUnit 3), and some classes use late static binding afaik, you should use `static::markTestSkipped('');` instead of `$this->`. It will generate a warning in newer PHP Versions. Signature:  `public static function markTestSkipped($message = '')`

Comment: Needs a better example of the full unit test file. Not just a snippet.

Comment: @DanielW. the [official phpunit manual](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html#incomplete-and-skipped-tests.skipping-tests) has examples showing `$this->markTestSkipped()`

Comment: @nulll you can see [in the sourcecode of 6.5](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/9535c8ca4e0c096f22e53bade686884f3d0b6107/src/Framework/Assert.php), `markTestSkipped()` is still a static method.

Answer (score 42):

If you can deal with ignoring the whole file then

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="foo">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
            <exclude>./tests/path/to/excluded/test.php</exclude>
                ^-------------
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

</phpunit>
```

Comment: The tests take about 20min to run, is there an easy way to see how many tests it will run? currently, I have to wait till the first row is completed `.......  63 / 893 (  7%)`

Comment: @Filype: then you probably specified the wrong path. It works well for me. Not sure if it is possible to get tests count. PS: unit tests should not run so long. I'd recommend using `@group` annotation and split tests by their nature

Answer (score 36):

Sometimes it's useful to skip all tests from particular file based on custom condition(s) defined as php code. You can easily do that using setUp function in which makeTestSkipped works as well.

```
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    
    if (your_custom_condition) {
        $this->markTestSkipped('all tests in this file are invactive for this server configuration!');
    }
}
```

*your_custom_condition* can be passed via some static class method/property, a constant defined in phpunit bootstrap file or even a global variable.

***Note:*** Don't forget calling `parent::setUp()` (see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/testing#creating-tests)).

Comment: What is a ```Config``` class? Where do I place it?

Comment: @cronfy it can be any global scope accessible class (Singleton / Register design pattern) or even global variable set in bootstrap file in phpunit. Basically the logic is: if ($testsFromThisFileShouldBeSkipped) { $this->markTestSkipped(...); }

Comment: remove the conditional and your answer would be straight forward... "markTestSkipped inside the setup to skip the whole file"

Comment: @SparK I see your point but I was providing way of _conditional_ skipping of whole test class. I've changed it a little, removing my custom way of doing it in favor of general rule.