# Scrutinizer - skip some phpunits

Tags: phpunit, scrutinizer

I want to skip some phpunit tests in scrutinizer.

How can I achive the same?

Where do I need to do configuration changes for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many CI systems incl. Scrutinizer CI set environment variables in their build environment.

For example the environment variable `SCRUTINIZER` is set to `TRUE`. That is only one of many, learn more about [Pre-defined Environment Variables on Scrutinizer CI](https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/build/environment-variables).

Inside the test method (or inside the `setUp()` method for the whole class) you can check the environment variable (e.g. via `$_ENV`) and mark the test as skipped.

```
if (isset($_ENV['SCRUTINIZER'])) {
    $this->markTestSkipped(
        'Scrutinizer CI build'
    );
}
```

See as well the more general question [How to skip tests in PHPunit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239264/how-to-skip-tests-in-phpunit) and the Phpunit documentation [Incomplete and Skipped Tests](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.3/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html#skipping-tests).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have added 
`./vendor/bin/phpunit --exclude-group Group1, Group2` command as follows in .scrutinizer.yml file at application level to skip phpunits representing these groups as follows :

```
build:
    nodes:
        acsi:
            tests:
                override:
                    - './vendor/bin/phpunit --exclude-group Group1, Group2'
                    - phpcs-run --standard=phpcs.xml
                    - php-scrutinizer-run
```